# REVINFO table is missing the sequence "revinfo_seq"

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I am migrating to SpringBoot 3.0.1 and updated "hibernate-envers" version to "6.1.6.Final". My DB is PostgreSQL 13.6.
Hibernate is configured to create the DB schema:
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:create`

After starting the application I get the following error:

```
pim 2022-12-27 12:00:13,715 WARN  C#c7b942ec-33b4-4749-b113-22cbb2946a8d [http-nio-9637-exec-1]     SqlExceptionHelper/133              - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
pim 2022-12-27 12:00:13,715 ERROR C#c7b942ec-33b4-4749-b113-22cbb2946a8d [http-nio-9637-exec-1]     SqlExceptionHelper/138              - ERROR: relation "revinfo_seq" does not exist
  Position: 16
```

The revinfo table look like this:

```
create table revinfo
(
    revision           bigint not null
        primary key,
    client_id          varchar(255),
    correlation_id     varchar(255),
    origin             varchar(255),
    request_id         varchar(255),
    revision_timestamp bigint not null,
    timestamp_utc      timestamp with time zone,
    user_name          varchar(255)
);
```

The sequence "revinfo_seq" does not exist, but in the old DB structure with envers

```
5.6.8.Final
```

and SpringBoot 2.6.6 it didn't exist either without any problems.
What am i Missing?

I tried to toggle the paramter

```
org.hibernate.envers.use_revision_entity_with_native_id
```

but it did not help.

Comment: Same problem here. Spring Boot 3.0.1. Previously, with 2.7.7 worked just fine.
`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [revinfo_seq]`

Comment: In my case, my schema is created with Liquibase. And worked fine with previous versions.
In my PostgreSQL instance, I can see that the sequence is named in a different way: revinfo_rev_seq

Comment: I switched off Liquibase and now use Hibernate only.
With SpringBoot 2.6.6: When using Hibernate 5.6.7 together with Hibernate-envers 5.6.8 the sequence "revinfo_seq" is created during application startup and everything works fine.
With SpringBoot 3.0.1: When using Hibernate 6.1.6 together with Hibernate-envers 6.1.6 no sequence like "revinfo_seq" or "revinfo_rev_seq" is created and an error occurs when trying to do an insert to the table.
I think I will raise an issue to th envers project.

Comment: Same problem here, envers, spring boot 3.0 and liquibase. `revinfo_rev_seq` always was created in spring boot 2.x and is still be created in 3.x. I tried renaming it to `revinfo_seq` but the error message stays the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can solve it with this property:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy: legacy`

Tested with Spring Boot 3.0.1

**Reason**:

Hibernate 6 changed the sequence naming strategy, so it was searching for a sequence ending with "_seq".
You can read a really detailed explanation here: https://thorben-janssen.com/sequence-naming-strategies-in-hibernate-6/

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. There is also some nice info over at the JpaBuddy site. https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/hibernate6-whats-new-and-why-its-important/

Answer (score 3):

Switching the naming strategy didn't help in my case. I created a custom revision entity and set the id generation strategy to identity to solve the problem:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity
@Table(name="revinfo")
public class RevInfoEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @RevisionNumber
    @Column(name="rev")
    private long rev;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    @Column(name="revtstmp")
    private LocalDateTime revtstmp;
}
```

If you store the timestamp as bigint, you may have to change the type of revtstmp to long.

Comment: The custom revision entity worked for me as well. The revtmsmp comment was also helpful. The legacy behavior changed in the accepted answer caused other issues for me.